# Cloud firestore - Order by nested data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase cloud firestore. My database structure looks something like in the picture below. So, basically I have got a document for 'Liked' which tracks the timestamp at which user has liked the content. It has got 'chapter' as subcollection and inside each chapter there are sub-chapters which has the actual timestamp. Now I want to retrieve all the liked data ordered by the timestamp. I am not sure how can I achieve this!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use `orderBy()` to specify the sort order for your data like shown in the following example:

```
db.collection("liked").orderBy('timestamp').get()
```

I would also suggest you to follow [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), it demostrates how to set up Cloud Firestore, add, read data and secure data.

**UPDATE**

I created the following database to replicate your scenario:

```
reprod(collections)/
        test1(document)/
            liked(collections)/
                        0(document)/
                              type(filed)
```

To stream the timestamps in ascending order I iterated manually to the doc and fetched the data ordered by timestamp:

```
reprod = db.collection(u'reprod').document(u'test1').collection(u'liked')
timestamps = reprod.stream()
for doc in timestamps:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

To do that I used the Firestore documentation on how to [retrieve data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and how to [order data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Comment: Hi, I have been through the source, but your response doesn't answer what I'm looking for. If you see the description and the image, I have a nested structured where the timestamp is actually stored.